# Infragistics UltraWebGrid - Selected Row changes randomly

Tags: asp.net, events, client-side, infragistics, ultrawebgrid

We are using Version=11.1.20111.2064 of Infragistics35.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.v11.1 and we are experiencing trouble in selecting a row. When a person selects a row near the bottom of the grid, the selected row changes to a row near the top after a few seconds. While mousing over the grid, the control seems to refresh itself a couple of times. In the end the user is frustrated because they never see the row they selected unless it is at the top.

What could be causing this? I know that I can override the client side events, but I am not sure if this is the right approach. I have the same control on another page and it does not behave the same way.

DH

Answer (score 0):

Do you display any alert messages to the user in `AfterSelectChangeHandler` event? If so it could trigger a bug when mouse move causes row selection. If that's the case add at the end of your AfterSelectChangeHandler handler:

```
igtbl_getGridById(gridName).Element.setAttribute('mouseDown', 0);
```

Ref: http://codecorner.galanter.net/2011/11/15/ultrawebgrid-bug-row-is-selected-on-mouse-move/

Comment: We do not display an alert. It just seems that the grid refreshes and renders continually. The first time it renders, it takes quite a while, changing width and height many times. When an item is selected it refreshes and only displays items at the top.

Comment: Can u describe what client/server -side events of grid you're using and what they're doing?

Comment: grd.DisplayLayout.ClientSideEvents.AfterSelectChangeHandler = "RowActivate";


function RowActivate(gridName, itemName) {
    var id = gridName.replace(/x/g, "_");
    var baseId = GetBaseId(id);
    document.getElementById(baseId + "btnEdit").disabled = false;    
    return true;
}

Comment: Do you also handle server-side SelectedRowChanged event? If so - do you rebind the grid in that handler?

Comment: No, we don't handle this event.

Comment: Something makes the grid Refresh. You may have to run JS Profiler and see what is called during row select and following mouse move

Comment: It looks like igtbl_getParentCell, igbtl_clearSelectionAll ... quite a number of functions are called. Is there any in particular I should look for?

Comment: @Dylan It would help if you would post the markup showing what properties you have set on the UltraWebGrid as well as posting the relevant JavaScript in the question so it is easier to read than in the comments.